# How can I set up a server using swifter?

Tags: ios, swift, server

https://github.com/glock45/swifter
Swifter is tiny http server engine written in Swift programming language.When I run it on my mac, the console shows `Server started!` But I don't know how to open it using a browser and how to transfer data to the server. I am new in programming and computer network. Can anyone kindly tell me?

Comment: would like to know the security pitfalls of running this inside a sandboxed application on iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [`HttpServer`](https://github.com/glock45/swifter/blob/master/Common/HttpServer.swift) class, if you don't specify a port number it will listen on 8080, which is the de facto goto port for secondary web servers - this will have been chosen to avoid conflicting with Apache which is likely pre-loaded on your *iOS* and uses the *default* HTTP port 80.

So to access your server locally you can visit: http://localhost:8080

---

If you'd prefer - and are sure Apache isn't in use on your machine - you may also start the server on port 80 by passing it as an argument to the `start` method in order to avoid having to specify it in the browser / request URI:

```swift
let server = HttpServer()
// ...
server.start(80)
```